# FFmpegMediaPlayer: findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I use https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer in my application, but some Android device throw exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at ru.mypackage.PlayService.initPlayer(PlayService.java:74)
at ru.mypackage.PlayService.onCreate(PlayService.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1949)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:989)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load avutil: findLibrary returned null
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
at wseemann.media.FFmpegMediaPlayer.<clinit>(FFmpegMediaPlayer.java:620)
... 13 more
```

My project:
[image]
[image]

Can somebody explain me what's wrong there?
On my device and some other device the app working nice, but on some device (for example: Galaxy Ace (GT-S5830i) Android 2.3.3 - 2.3.7) it throw the exception.

p.s. about "lib" prefix I understood ( https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#mapLibraryName(java.lang.String) )

Answer (score 1):

You have to place the `armeabi` file under `jnilibs` folder (you will have to create it) in `app/src/main/`.
Hope it helps.